# Newbie Android Architecture query

Tags: android

I'm a C# Windows Phone 7 developer looking to port some apps over to Android and I'm new to both Java and android...

I have been through the Android Application Fundamentals and have developed some of the "View" app examples and have a couple questions...

1 - In WP7 we can run code in the "background" when our app is not running.  The OS wakes up our background program every half hour or so so we can quickly accomplish some task.  How is this done in Android?

2 - In WP7 we can post info to our "Tiles" so a user can, for instance, see the number of friends within a certain proximity just by looking at the phone.  I know Android does not have "tiles" but can we post info the application icon?  Or something like that?

Obviously I would have to be able to do #1 before I could do #2

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, take a look at [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). You can set it up to periodically call up your code to do some work. You can even tell it to wake/not wake the phone from standby to do your job. So for instance if your app is updating weather info you can choose not to wake up the phone to do that (since the user wont see the update anyway) and save battery.

Second, to provide information at a glance on Android you use [Widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) which the user can add to his homescreen if he wishes. You can think of them as a special kind of View.